# Use RelativeSizeSpan with TextView's textAllCaps at true is not working

Tags: android, spannable

All in the title.

Is it a bug or a desired behaviour ?
And in the last case, i can't understand why ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably a bug or mutual exclusion.

When `textAllCaps` is set `TextView` applies `TransformationMethod` that takes the text and converting it to plain `Strings` that makes source text `CharSequence` loose all other stylings and spans.

You can trick it programatically like (Kotlin naive):

```
 val text = textView.text // at this point allCaps is applied so text is caps
 textView.setAllCaps(false) // remove the allCaps
 val spannable = SpannableString(text) // create new spannable with allCapped text 
 spannable.setSpan(RelativeSizeSpan(1f), 0, text.length, SpannableString.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
 textView.text = spannable //set it.
```

Another approach is creating your own `TransformationMethod` that will apply your Span for every text that is set.

Comment: A bug indeed, fixed in Oreo. I've reported the issue, for a possible fix in the AppCompatTextView. Please star: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140956412